# Can't use compass after installing it

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, vagrant, compass-sass

I don't seem to be able to get compass working on Vagrant using [this Vagrantfile](https://github.com/Ilyes512/Vaprobash/blob/compass/Vagrantfile). See the rest of the bash script's used right <strike>here</strike>(removed repo) (see [Vaprobash](http://fideloper.github.io/Vaprobash/index.html) if you want to provision your Vagrant Ubuntu Box!).

So I was fallowing a gruntjs course, when I had to use `grunt server`. The only problem is that it needs a newer ruby version (1.9+ I believe instead of the 1.8) and it needs compass. So I have solved the ruby part by installing RVM and installing the latest stable version. Compass should be easy to get `gem install compass` and it does seem to be installed. But when I type in `compass -v` I get the fallowing error:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

So I am not sure what is going wrong except for the error telling me it's missing files. Anyone got some hints to what could be the problem?

.bash_profile contains the path info:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

`rvm -v` and `ruby -v` work just fine and after installing `gem install compass` `sass -v` seem to work as well.

You can replicate everything using Vagrant and VirtualBox. Just download the Vagrantfile from my github mentioned above and `vagrant up`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I asked for help on the official compass Github issue's page and got the answer for this problem.

The GitHub issue is right [here](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1513).

How to fix this:

When installing compass (v0.12.2), it will download the latest sass v3.3.0.rc3 (cause it's a dependency), but compass won't work with the latest sass. You either upgrade compass to the latest alpha version (0.13.*) or downgrade sass to 3.2.*. I choose the last one:

```
gem uninstall sass --version 3.3.0.rc.3
gem install sass --version 3.2.18
compass -v # Working :)
```

Make sure you use the version you got installed. Find out by typing this:

```
sass --version
```

Comment: I had a very similar issue when trying to install on Mac OS X Mavericks with the stock ruby and these steps solved it, thank you!

Comment: Great!! I've been looking for a while. I'm on Ubuntu by the way!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082978/497756 - it was for other problem but should solve yours too.

Comment: Ok, so I fallowed every step after a fresh Vagrant box provisioning and the output of `ls $GEM_HOME/wrappers/compass` = `/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/compass`. Not sure what to do with the result. I still get the same error when using `compass -v'.BTW, I am not using Codekit if that was what you thought?

Comment: try `/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/compass -v`

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well and got the same thing. I also want to say that I havent used any `sudo`, but if I do `sudo gem list` and `gem list` I get 2 different lists. Compass however I only installed in the list without `sudo` so that seems right.

Comment: then you should check both `/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/environment` and `/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/compass` maybe there is a bug?