# compass installation does not work anymore

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass-sass

Using Mac Mountain Lion

### **My compass installation does not work any more**

I used brew, rvm, gem sometimes together with sudo (yes meanwhile I know this was not a good idea) - I have to admit that I do not have a clear picture which parts of rvm could conflict with the native ruby installation or with installations from brew…

```
compass install compass
```

gives me:

> $ compass install compass
>   /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in`block in '
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in`'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in`block in '
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in`'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in`fallback_load_path'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/compass:23:in`load'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>       from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

then

```
which -a gem
```

results in:

```
/Users/marc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

After I learned today that I should not use sudo when installing sass and compass I deinstalled sass and compass using sudo. Following that I did a gem install compass without sudo.

Unfortunately same error as above.

So this does not have an impact.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does "compass watch" say it cannot load sass/script/node (LoadError)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877028/why-does-compass-watch-say-it-cannot-load-sass-script-node-loaderror)

Answer (score 1):

Has been solved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079342/cant-use-compass-after-installing-it) entry.
Have gone back to an earlier Sass version and everything is fine.